# Adding Results of a query from different tables To A new Table In PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, output

I have 20 tables and I wanted to perform a same query from all of them. Subsequently, I want to add the result of the all the queries to a new table. Tables include temperature, coordinate and time_date columns. And query is about creating sub-set of each table. The resulted new table should include the result of each query. In other words it should include aforementioned 3 column which are filled by the result of query from different tables.

The aforementioned code which should be applied for all the tables. is:

```
select *
FROM s3
WHERE dt::timestamptz BETWEEN DATE '2007-09-14' AND DATE '2007-10-03' 
  AND extract(hour FROM dt::timestamptz) BETWEEN 8 AND 20
ORDER BY dt
```

As a result there should be a new table which include temperature, coordinate and time_date columns with respect to the output of the query form all the tables.
Note: Sequence of filling is not important in a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use `union all`:

```
create table T as
select * from ...
union all
select * from ...
union all
...
```